# Character repeating in a string

Tags: python, string, repeat

can you please tell me how to get every character in a string repeated using the for loop in python?my progress is as far as :

```
def double(str):
    for i in range(len(str)):
        return i * 2
```

and this returns only the first letter of the string repeated

Comment: The reason why it only returns the first letter repeated is because the `return` statement ends the method execution and returns whatever value you want it (in this case `i*2`).  You want to build up the output string, then `return` outside the loop (when the loop is completed).

Comment: using yield instead of return would make it a generator, and calling list on your function would return all the content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to print each character of the input string twice, in order. The issue with your attempt is your use of `return`. You only want to return the final string, not just a single repetition of one character from inside the loop. So you want your return statement to be somehow outside the for-loop.

Since this sounds like a homework problem, try to figure out how to do that above before continuing below.

Still stuck?

Print each character in a string twice, in order:

```
def double(str):
    outstr = ''
    for character in str:
        outstr = outstr + character + character
    return outstr
```

Without using a for-loop:

```
def double(str):
    return ''.join([c+c for c in str])
```

Comment: 1 typo to fix:
outstr = outstr + character + character

Answer (score 2):

General variation, which returns string, repeating each character in the original string **n** times:

```
def multichar(text, n):
    return ''.join([x * n for x in text])
```

**Explanation**:

`''.join(...)` - glues everything in (...) together into one piece *without* spaces, i.e. `''.join('a', 'b', 'c')` will return `'abc'`.

`' '.join('a', 'b', 'c')` will return `'a b c'`.

`'-'.join('a', 'b', 'c')` will return `'a-b-c'`.

...you get the idea :)

`[x * n ...]` - repeats `x` `n` times, i.e. `'a' * 3` gives `'aaa'`.

`[... for x in text]` - normal `for` loop - goes over every element in `text`.

**Plain English** for what the last line of the code does:

Glue without spaces every element in the list, generated by repeating `x` `n` times for every `x` in `text`.

**Example**:

```
>>> multichar('Hello', 2)
```

will return:

```
>>> 'HHeelllloo'
```

Answer (score 1):

given a string, the below code repeats every original character in the string twice with the help of functions and while loop.
res is a list that stores the doubled characters of the string. " ".join() is called to connect the list. 
the number of times that the original character is repeated can be changed. 
 here's the code snippet.

```
def paper_doll(text):
j = len(text)  
i=0
res=[]
while i<j :

    res.append(text[i]*2)
    i = i+1
result ="".join(res)
print(result)
```

paper_doll('paperdoll')

OUTPUT :

```
ppaappeerrddoollll
```

open to any kind of feedback and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

With minimal modification to existing code:

(`range(len))` would iterate over indices, not actual chars, and `yield` instead of `return` makes it a generator thus allowing to return all values)

```
def double(str):
    for i in str:
        yield i * 2
```

Use it as so:

```
str = 'This is a test'
''.join(double(str))
```

Comment: it's an online exercise so i had to use for loop and a return statement. Plus i haven't yet studied yield

Answer (score 0):

```
str = input('Enter string: ')
char = " "
for i in char:
    char = char + i + i
print(char)
```

Comment: 1. Add an explanation. 2. You want to loop over `str`, not `char`.

Comment: Additionally you probably shouldn't be trying to overwrite builtin functions like `str`

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_3(letter):
    a = []
    for i in range(0,len(letter)):
        a.append(letter[i]*3)
    return ''.join(a)
# call the function
print(time_3('HELLO'))
```

Output:

```
HHHEEELLLLLLOOO
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).